# How can I get data from multiple attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get data from multiple attributes on click event. Suppose I have a div with class `test_class` and ID `testID` as given below.

```
<div class="test_class" id="testId"><!-- ... --></div>
```

I want to get the value of the `class` and `id` attributes and store them in separate variables.

```
var classattr = 'test_class';
var idattr = 'testId';
```

How can I make this? I would like to avoid calling [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) multiple times.

Comment: use `.attr()` like `$("#testId").attr("id")` for id and `$("#testId").attr("class")` for class

Comment: @guradio Is there is any way to get the values in once I mean I don't have to use attr() multiple times

Comment: you are still going to use `.attr()` map them in an array using map and getting `.attr()`

Comment: Store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log("Div id is "+$('div').attr('id'))
console.log("Div class is "+$('div').attr('class'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test_class" id="testId"></div>
```

1. Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

   > Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can get those with javascript too, like below.

```js
var attrs = document.getElementById("testId").attributes;
var classattr = attrs["class"].nodeValue;
var idattr = attrs["id"].nodeValue;
console.log(classattr);
console.log(idattr);
```

```html
<div class="test_class" id="testId">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler with object destruction:

```js
var t = document.getElementById("testId");

var {className, id} = t;

console.log(className, id)
```

```html
<div class="test_class" id="testId">
```

You can add any other attributes between surly braces if you need.

Answer (score 1):

***USE***:

```
$(this).each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    // this.attributes is not a plain object, but an array
    // of attribute nodes, which contain both the name and value
    if(this.specified) {
      console.log(this.name, this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

You will not have to use .attr multiple times.
For eg: a single **span** tag with multiple attributes can be obtained using the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery at all. By the magic of vanilla JavaScript, you can already access the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) and [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) of any element you have. There is even a neater interfaces for adding/removing classes: [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). You can use them as follows, in a jQuery click handler:

```js
$('.test_class').click(function() {
  console.log(this.className, this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test_class" id="testId">Click me!</div>
```

Or without any jQuery:

```js
document.querySelector('.test_class').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.className, this.id);
});
```

```html
<div class="test_class" id="testId">Click me!</div>
```

---

To access other attributes, you can use other methods.

- `data-*` attributes? Use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- `name` attribute? Well... [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name).
- Attribute that cannot be accessed directly? [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) has you covered.

Comment: but what if I have data-* attr and name attr

Comment: @user7791702 Ah, that was not in your question. I edited my answer to include some other types of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is when a certain button has been pressed. lets say the class btn has been clicked.

```
<html>

    <a href="#" class="button">Click me</a>
    <div class="test_class" id="testId> Some stuff in here </div>

</html>

<script>

    $("").click(function(){

var dvclass = $(".test_class").attr("class");
var dvid = $(".test_class").attr("id");


});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDomNodeProps(domNode) {
    let attrs = {}
    Array.from(domNode.attributes).forEach(a => attrs[a.name] = a.value);
    return attrs;
}
console.log(getDomNodeProps(document.getElementById("testId")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`attr()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb3oPiv7DUAhVHQY8KHX4AC9IQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg&sig2=FiAzJ2o4WOH2o6wq6L3zOw).And do with click function .Then find the attr value using `this.attr`

```js
$('.test_class').click(function() {
  var cls = $(this).attr('class');
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log(cls, id)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test_class" id="testId">click</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").click(function(){
            var clnm=$(this).attr("class");
            var idSel=$(this).attr("id");
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="test_class" id="testId">
    Example
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>




$("div").click(function(){
var classattr=$(this).attr("class");
var idattr=$(this).attr("id");
console.log(classattr,idattr);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this).each(function() {
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
    // this.attributes returns array
    if(this.specified) {
      console.log(this.name, this.value);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.